# How to hide divs when resizing child divs inside a parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some divs inside a container, and each child div is jQuery resizable that handles e resize.

My problem is when I try to resize the first child, the others jump outside the content div or outside when they reach the limits of their parent,

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/don_dasa/vS8vu/3/) you can see a working example.

What I need is, when resize any child none of them jump outside the parent or to a new line and if the parent reach the max-width hide the overflow.

Any help will be great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you have a bunch of bounds settings for your container so this will probably be a no but... Would setting a `height:50px` on your `.container` CSS a viable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container is jumping to the new line because you set a range of 50-100px for the height in the css.

Change

```
max-height: 200px;
```

To

```
max-height: 50px;
```

on `.container`.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vS8vu/5/

Comment: Sorry.. but that didn't work! it keeps jumping to new line :(, just delete the overflow attribute and you'll see..

Comment: Well... of course it would in your scenario. Please look up what overflow is. I'm not sure why you unaccepted the answer as your answer was answered per your requirements. If you have a new question feel free to create a new question.